# Can I make multiple Lua VM in single thread?

Tags: multithreading, lua, instance, virtual-machine

As I know, I can make a Lua VM for each thread. But I'm not sure about multiple instances in a thread. Is this possible?

Comment: Technically your not creating a VM, your creating a state and execution context for the VM to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple states, but without threads or multiple processes, you'll only be able to run one of them at a time.  Also, you cannot communicate between states in Lua's core, so you'll either need to write your own or find a library to perform any synchronization or inter-state communication.

Comment: What's the meaning of *able to run only one at a time*? Is this mean multiple instance is possible, but no concurrent execution in a thread?

Comment: When you execute Lua code from your program, it runs until you get the result, just like any other function.  The same rules apply to make this run concurrently as would apply for running any function concurrently.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can just call the creation function repeatedly.

Comment: Does it mean multiple VMs can work separated and concurrently in a thread?

Comment: With a signle thread hosting multiple VMs, they would run cooperatively - not concurrently. You would need to implement your own scheduler or using something like http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/

Answer (score 0):

comparing two object references using the == operator to true only when both references to the same object .